# hide() show() jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following:

`$('#info').click(function (){
$('#message').fadeIn(200).show();
return false;
});`

How could I change my script so that it would dissapear once clicked apon again?

Tried `.fadeout().hide()`

But it only show/hide so fast it looks as though nothing is happening.

Comment: fadeIn().show() is redundant, after fading in, it is already shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#info').click( function(){
   $('#message').fadeToggle(200);
   return false;
});
```

to make it fade in and out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('#info').click(
    function(){
       $('#message').toggle();
       return false;
    });
```

Using jQuery's [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

---

**Edited** to change from plain ol' `toggle()` to the slightly more in-keeping with the question [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/):

```
$('#info').click(
    function(){
        $('#message').fadeToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo, featuring `fadeToggle()`](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J9vtq/).

There is, of course, *also* [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle), which may be used similarly.

Answer (score -1):

`$('#info').click(function (){ $('#message').fadeIn(200).toggle(); return false; });`

Comment: this would never leave the message shown, as it would fadeIn and then .toggle() hidden.